# How to provide SQL cast in Spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I've a table in postgres which stores IP address (inet data type). I am querying it as following -

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);


    Map<String, Object> params = new HashedMap();
        Collection<Object> ipList = new LinkedList<>();
        ips.add("1.2.3.4");
        ips.add("5.6.7.8");

    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("select * from myTable source_ip in (:ipList)",
            params, new RowMapper<Object>() {
              @Nullable @Override public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                System.out.println(rs.toString());
                return null;
              }
            });
```

Above code fragment gives me DB exception- 
`No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

I looked into `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class` source code and found no way to specify parameter data type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've extended the extended the method `getPreparedStatementCreator` in `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` such that it appends a sql cast variable to the "?" in the prepared statement

Comment: Any chance you can provide this example for us novice folk?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you missed to add ipList to parameters map:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashedMap<>();
Collection<Object> ipList = new ArrayList<>();
ipList.add("1.2.3.4");
ipList.add("5.6.7.8");
params.put("ipList", ipList);
```

but I suggest to use:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("ipList", Arrays.asList("1.2.3.4", "5.6.7.8"));
```